# Render xml (from an exe) to a new window

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm trying to render (on client side) some XML data retrieved from an EXE (on server side).
I can't add any link to an XSLT stylesheet in the XML data, so I'm looking for a javascript function that could transform the XML through my XSLT (which can be stored on the server).

Currently, my webpage opens the XML using :

```
onclick="openWindow('Exe/the_url_and_args')"
```

I have no problem in creating an XSLT but I don't know how to call that file using javascript ! Can't find anything relevant googling :(
Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The Sarissa API is often used as a portable cross-browser API for invoking XSLT 1.0 transformations from Javascript.

These days you can also use XSLT 2.0 in the browser using Saxon-CE, whose Javascript API is described here:

http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/api/intro.xml

In many cases, Saxon-CE does the whole job for you, so you don't need to write any Javascript at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far, looks like it matches my need ! But as I'm not a developer, I'm trying to figure out how to implement this code in my project. I think this function `Sarissa.updateContentFromURI(sFromUrl, oTargetElement, xsltproc, callback, skipCache)` could be the one, but I don't get how to insert the xslt code... Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: One of our motivations in the design of Saxon-CE was to enable people who aren't programmers to create interactive web content. Of course, only time will tell whether we achieve that aim. Meanwhile, I find it very hard to help someone who is trying to write Javascript and tells me that they are not a developer; it's like helping someone to land an aircraft when they tell you they have no pilot's training.